# innerText of element does not display var

Tags: javascript

I'm using the below code to display the e-mail address of the user, but the result is completely blank where the e-mail should be.

```
function newUserSendVerificationEmail() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    let user_email = user.email
    console.log('newUserSendVerificationEmail user is ', user)
    console.log('newUserSendVerificationEmail user_email is ' + user_email)
    user.sendEmailVerification().then(function () {
        question_text.innerText = "Please verify your account by clicking the link I sent to \n\n", user_email
        newUserWaitForEmailVerification()
    }).catch(function (error) {
        question_text.innerText = "Error"
    })
}
```

This is what it looks like.

[image]

And here's the console output showing the email var has a value.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't concatenate strings with a comma in javascript - you use `+`. However, a more modern approach is to use template literals and backticks. Plus since you're putting in formatting (line breaks) this is really more of HTML than text. Try this

```
question_text.innerHTML = `Please verify your account by clicking the link I sent to <br/><br/> ${user_email}`;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to remove the break tags because they weren't working, but the e-mail address showed up so that's good enough for me, or I can just add '\n\n' to it separately.

Comment: My mistake, I was using innerText instead of innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try using innerHTML instead of innerText. I have had similar issues and it worked. Good luck!

```
question_text.innerHTML = `Please verify your account by clicking the link I sent to <br/><br/> ${user_email}`;
```

Edit: Realized that the other reply said the exact same thing... Sorry!

Comment: Thanks yeah that was my mistake, I didn't realize the answer used innerHTML instead of innerText so I didn't change it in my code. I appreciate it.